# Каким образом получить город и страну?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api

Здравствуйте. Есть скрипт, с помощью которого, при вводе первых букв названия города, появляется список городов. Все работает замечательно.

Вопрос: Каким образом получить страну и город в отдельные поля **input** . 
Например, я ввожу **Москва**, появляется список и я выбираю *Москва, город Москва, Россия* , значит в поле `input name="strana"` должно появится **Россия**, а в поле `input name="gorod"` - **Москва**.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

```js
      function initialize() {

        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');

        var options = {
          types: ['(cities)'],
        };

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace(); //получаем место
          console.log(place);
          console.log(place.name);  //название места
          console.log(place.id);  //уникальный идентификатор места
        });

      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBsqnZcch_56fMZAFOeO_eSh2nsqqLFWGY&amp;libraries=places"></script>


Введите город: <input id="searchTextField" size="50" type="text" /><br /><br />
Страна: <input name="strana" size="50" type="text" /><br />
Город: <input name="gorod" size="50" type="text" /><br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function initialize() {

        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');

        var options = {
          types: ['(cities)'],
        };

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace(); //получаем место
          // массив адресов 
          var address = place.address_components;
          // населенный пункт в нулевом элементе
          document.getElementById('city').value = address[0].long_name;
          // страна в элементе, который в подмассиве types содержит элемент со значением 'country'
          for (var i = address.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            if (address[i].types.indexOf("country") !== -1) {
               document.getElementById('country').value = address[i].long_name; 
              break;
            }
          }

          console.log(address);
//          console.log(place);
//          console.log(place.name);  //название места
//          console.log(place.id);  //уникальный идентификатор места
        });

      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBsqnZcch_56fMZAFOeO_eSh2nsqqLFWGY&amp;libraries=places"></script>


Введите город: <input id="searchTextField" size="50" type="text" /><br /><br />
Страна: <input id="country" name="strana" size="50" type="text" /><br />
Город: <input id="city" name="gorod" size="50" type="text" /><br />
```

Answer (score 2):

// Добавил id

`<input name="strana" id="strana" size="50" type="text" /><br />
<input name="gorod" id="gorod" size="50" type="text" /><br />`

// Получаем элемент и присваиваем значение.

`document.getElementById("gorod").value = place.name;
 document.getElementById("strana").value = place.address_components[3].long_name;`

Comment: Рассматривал такой вариант. Город получить - нет проблем. А вот с выбором страны из массива - проблема. Объектов в массиве не всегда одинаковое количество...

Comment: var strana = place.formatted_address.split(', ');
document.getElementById("strana").value = strana[1];

Comment: Так же можно перебрать все объекты и провести сравнение. Придется создать массив и прописать все сокращения стран. 
var country = [
 'BY','UA', 'US','RU'
];
   
place.address_components.forEach(function (obj){
 country.forEach(function (country) {
  if(obj.short_name == country){
   console.log('long_name', obj.long_name)
  }
 });
});